# ng-table not working | inject error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I'm getting this error when using, ng-table.

```
angular.js:12332 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ngTableParamsProvider <- ngTableParams <- tableController
```

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/$injector/unpr?p0=ngTableParamsProvider%20%3C-%20ngTableParams%20%3C-%20tableController

The code is,

```
angular.module('ngTableTutorial', ['ngTable'])
    .controller('tableController', [ '$scope', '$filter', 'ngTableParams', function ($scope, $filter, ngTableParams) {
```

...

What is the correct way of resolving this issue ?

Comment: I guess you didn't load the js prior to load your angular code. Please try to load `<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/1.0.0/dist/ng-table.js"></script>` first and then check

Comment: It also seems to be case sensitive to `NgTableParams`

Comment: @Vineet It would report that the `ngTable` module was missing before it would report about the `ngTableParams` provider if that was the case.

Comment: @Vineet I refer to, ng-table.js prior to refer my app.js (which include the given code) bdw, the url that you are referring here is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that dependencies are case sensitive. `NgTableParams`

In their [example](http://ng-table.com/#/intro/demo-real-world) the injected dependency is included as `NgTableParams` not `ngTableParams`

Comment: I changed it to "NgTableParams", now I'm getting an error stating "ngTableParams" is not defined in my browser console. I'm trying to follow the given example in this web page.
http://4dev.tech/2015/08/tutorial-basic-datatable-sorting-filtering-and-pagination-with-angularjs-and-ng-table/

Comment: Are you definitely including ng-table in your application? And also inside your `angular.module('modulename', ['ngTable'])`